# Android でDBを内部ストレージにコピーしたい

Tags: android-studio

Android studioを使用してアプリを作っています。
下の画像の様に/data/data/cdProject.CDAndroid/databasesの下のデータベースCDSearch.dbとかは、アプリで作成できる仕様にしたのですが、他のDBはSDカードからコピーしたいのです。

SDKに入っている ADB Shell を使ってコピーしようとしても、Permission denied　が出てしまいます。
普通のファイル管理ツールでは、/data フォルダが出てこないです。

PCに接続しても内部ストレージで　/data フォルダが出てこないし、Androidのバージョンは13です。
同じソースでAndroid 7では `adb shell` でコピー可でした。

パーミッションを変えてみてもコピーできなくて、出来ないのではと思ってしまいました。
よろしくお願いします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]